# Llenar un textarea con un archivo que el usuario sube

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando una aplicación con Flask, tengo un botón con el cual el usuario sube un archivo. Quiero llenar un `textarea` con la información que contiene el archivo. Intente con el siguiente código que contiene la función que estoy utilizando.

```
<textarea id="data" name="data" cols="100" rows="50"></textarea>
<input type="file" id="file_u" name="file_u" onchange="fileSelect()" requiered>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var textbox = document.getElementById('data');
        var fileselect = document.getElementById('file_u');

        function fileSelect()
        {
            var x =  document.getElementById('file_u').value;
            var fileName = x.match(/[^\/\\]+$/);

            document.getElementById('data').value = fileName;
        }
    </script>
```

El único resultado que obtengo es el de que ponga el nombre del archivo en el `textarea`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba a usar la API de File

```
var file = document.getElementById("uploadData").files[0];
if (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        document.getElementById("file_u").innerHTML = evt.target.result;
    }
    reader.onerror = function (evt) {
        document.getElementById("file_u").innerHTML = "error";
    }
}
```

Comment: ¡Excelente si funciono!. Lo corregí ya que tenía mal unos campos. Muchas gracias